# Cp command does an extra copying on different Ubuntu version for folder cloning

Tags: ubuntu, cp

Edit: Found a duplicate with solution: rsync -a --delete  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698183/how-to-force-cp-to-overwrite-directory-instead-of-creating-another-one-inside

new script that works:

```
#!/bin/bash

numCopy=$1
shift
cmdline="${@}"
echo "prepare folders"
for ((i=1;i<=$numCopy;i++));
do
   (rsync -a --delete $cmdline/ $cmdline$i/; ) &
   (echo "preparing folder clone: $i") &
done
wait
```

---

For multithreaded folder copying,

```
#!/bin/bash

numCopy=$1
shift
cmdline="${@}"
echo "prepare folders"
for ((i=1;i<=$numCopy;i++));
do
   (cp -rf $cmdline $cmdline$i; ) &
   (echo "preparing folder clone: $i") &
done
wait
```

this script copies a source folder `$cmdline` to (non-existent) destination `$cmdline$i` without issue at my pc with **Ubuntu 16.04** but when I run same script on a cloud computer with **Ubuntu 18.04**, it does this:

- duplicates source as destination (I need only this)
- duplicates source into destination too (`destination/source` I don't want this)

this doesn't break any programs but I don't want to consume unnecessary cloud space.

Why would some different version of Ubuntu add a secondary copy into destination folder?

I'm using this script as

```
./myscript.sh 2 foldertest
```

this duplicates foldertest as foldertest1 and foldertest2. If first parameter is 32 then it makes 32 copies up to foldertest32.

Documentation of cp says -r is recursive copy which is I need to do full deep cloning of source folder just like copy pasting (in-place where it produces folder2 folder3 ...) in windows or graphical terminal of Ubuntu. Also I add -f to force it copy files without asking because I'm making up to 64 clones and don't want to answer 64 questions if there are already 64 clones.

Some extra info about the behaviour I need:

Folder A: a.txt b.txt c.txt

Folder A1,A2,A3,A4.. to be:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

but instead it is:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
A
```

normally when I copy file to file, it overwrites(if it exists). I need same overwrite behavior on folders, not copying into.

Comment: What do you mean with "it duplicates the source into the destination too"? I don't understand. :(

Comment: I need a folder "foldera" deep copied over a new folder "folderb" which doesn't exist or not. But it does extra copy that makes "folderb/foldera" duplicating its size. It makes a new folder but that new folder contains source  as a whole too. There are N files in source folder, ther are copied which is ok but it also copies source "into" destination too not just "over".

Comment: There must be something very simple that I miss but can't see. Most probably I'm wrong and Linux is right but where?

Comment: Ok I found a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698183/how-to-force-cp-to-overwrite-directory-instead-of-creating-another-one-inside

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `cp -rf source dest` is different if `dest` already exists.

- If `dest` does not exist, it will create a copy of `source` with the name `dest`. Assuming `source` contains a file `f1`, it will create `dest/f1`.
- If `dest` exists as a directory and if `dest` does not contain a file named `source`, it will copy `source` with all its contents **into** `dest`. With the example above you will get `dest/source/f1`.
- If `dest` exists as a file and if `source` is a directory, the copying will fail.
- If `dest` exists as a directory and if `dest` contains a file named `source`, copying will fail.
- If `dest` exists as a file and if `source` is a file, it will overwrite `dest` with the contents of `source`.

If you want to remove any existing destination directory you could change `(cp -rf $cmdline $cmdline$i; ) &` into `(rm -rf $cmdline$i && cp -rf $cmdline $cmdline$i; ) &`.

Comment: Thank you. Does rsync exist on all distros? Is cp safer to use in newly created Ubuntu images of Amazon aws for example?

Comment: I think `rsync` is available on all distros, but you might have to install the package first. (I don't know if it gets installed by default.)